# Computing the geodesic curvature of the upper parallel of the torus

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

How would this be done? In a previous exercise we were asked to determine whether the minimum, maximum and upper parallels of the torus were geodesics, asymptotic curves, or lines of curvature. The hint at the back says use the fact that the absolute value of the geodesic curvature is the absolute value of the projection onto the tangent plane of the usual curvature. But I don't really know what this means. I'm new to geodesics and I'm trying to get a better visual feel for them. I know it can be done by brute force (parametrizing the torus and setting u=pi/2 etc..) but I feel theres a much nicer way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By "upper parallel", I am assuming you mean the topmost circle on the torus (where a horizontal plane placed on top would make contact).

**Hint**:  $$k_g = k \ \mathbf{N} \cdot (\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{T})$$

Where $k_g$ is the geodesic curvature, $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{T}$ the normal and tangent vectors to the curve respectively, and $\mathbf{n}$ the surface normal.  You don't have to do any horrendous calculations to find  $\mathbf{n}$; it should be intuitive. :)

The upper parallel is just a circle; what is its radius?  From there, what is its curvature?  $\mathbf{N}$?  $\mathbf{T}$?

If you get stuck on this part, remember you can parametrize the circle as $\langle r\cos(t), r\sin(t), z \rangle$, where $r$ is its radius and $z$ the constant height.

---

As an aside, can you see why this circle would be an asymptotic curve?

Comment: Ah I'm think I'm understanding it better now. So we have r=a thus k=1/a. I just found a method that computes the geodesic curvature by saying kg=kcos(theta) and since a'' x a' points down theta =pi and kg=(1/a)(-1). I now see how its an asymptotic curve because the angle between n and N is pi/2. How does this method reconcile with yours? That is how is kg=kcos(theta) the same as kN dot (n X T)?

Comment: You are correct about the asymptotic curve.  What are you calling $\theta$ in this case?  Your $k_g$ looks correct up to a sign, but I am getting $k_g = (1/a)$.  You are certainly very close.

Comment: they appear to be calling θ the angle between alpha'' cross alpha' (where alpha is the the upper parallel) and the normal to the surface and it points down due to the right hand rule. I don't understand that part. Also using your method, I see that kn= n/a, but how did you calculate n cross T?

Comment: I simply did $n \times T$ with the right hand rule, noting that $n$ = $\langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle$ and $T$ the tangent to the parallel.  From that, we get that $n \times T$ is pointing in the same direction as $N$.

Comment: @KajHansen It may be late but I think the circle(upper parallel) should be parapmentrized by the arc length, which is the definition of the textbook. And the parapmetrization above doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Gangmen no bother: an arbitrary parametrization $\mathbf{p}$ can be turned into one parametrized by arclength $\mathbf{a}$ by taking $\mathbf{a}(t) = \mathbf{p}(t)/||\mathbf{p}(t)||$.

Comment: @KajHansen Well, that's right, and I may make it clear